# How to fetch Sharepoint data and load into Azure Blob Storage using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, odata, sharepoint-2013, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I want to load data from Sharepoint to Azure Blob Storage using Azure Data Factory.
Although I don't know anything about OData but seems it is possible using Odata as mentioned in  following tutorial [Copy data from OData source to Azure Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-odata-connector#json-example-copy-data-from-odata-source-to-azure-blob)

I have setup everything as per the tutorial but it is not working.

Please help/suggest if I am missing something.

Below is the configuration I am using for OData linked servce in Azure Data Factory.

```
{
    "name": "LS_OData",
    "properties": {
        "hubName": "adf_hub",
        "type": "OData",
        "typeProperties": {
            "url": "http://flic.xyzc.com/Sites/WYST/Lists/RAZXE/AllItems.aspx)",
            "authenticationType": "Basic",
            "username": "usrname",
            "password": "**********",
            "gatewayName": "myGateway"
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE - I am able to get the data using the same URL/credentials using SharePoint REST APIs.
Also, I have Data Management Gateway installed and working fine for OnPremise SQL and Oracle databases.

Comment: When you say "not working" - are you getting an error message?  You should check the datasets associated with the data factory in the portal.

Comment: Thanks for replying @wBob the issue was with the URL that was not as per the OData services.

Comment: We also could get the answer from your mentioned [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-odata-connector#json-example-copy-data-from-odata-source-to-azure-blob).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of OData, You can also use SharePoint REST API Directly.

Obtain the REST API endpoint for your SharePoint data. Generally, it looks like: `https://<your-domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site-name>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<List Name>')/items`.

Create Linked Services in Azure Data Factory. HTTP Linked Service using the Base URL (SharePoint REST endpoint). Use 'Basic' or another suitable authentication method.

Create a New Dataset, For SharePoint, select the `HTTP` dataset type. Configure it to use the `HTTP Linked Service` you created. Specify the relative URL if needed, and other configurations.

Now you can use a Copy Data Pipeline. For the source, select the SharePoint datase. For the destination, select the Azure Blob Storage dataset and Map the fields if necessary.

SharePoint REST API has limitations on the number of items returned in one request, so you might have to handle pagination if you're working with large lists.